# Disambiguate [hashbang] and [shebang]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

[hashbang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hashbang) is currently used for a mixture of questions about hashbangs in URLs and questions about Unix shebangs, while [shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shebang) is purely about the latter.

Having both these topics covered by a single tag seems unhelpful, since they are unrelated.

Both terms are valid in reference to either concept, but in my experience the word "shebang" seems to be more popular in reference to Unix shebangs and the word "hashbang" seems to be more popular in reference to URL hashbangs.

Shall we retag all Unix questions currently tagged "hashbang" as "shebang", instead, and then modify the Wiki summary of "hashbang" to indicate that it should only be used for URL hashbangs, not Unix shebangs?

Comment: I wonder, is this actually useful?

Comment: http://youtu.be/eMNNDJ-zfKI?t=1m12s

Comment: I remember back when [the term "hashbang" wasn't even a thing yet](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3009380/1) (except little more than a less common synonym of "shebang"). I also just noticed that my question has now been edited to remove "shebang" from the title and tags - the retag is fine but I'm not entirely sure if the title edit was warranted considering the whole premise of the question was, like I said in my question and here, that `#!` was at the time mainly used in Unix and thus known as a shebang, and anyone with experience in the latter could potentially have the same question.

Comment: Can you *really* be an expert on [shebang]?

Comment: @PierreArlaud there is room for a few levels of knowledge... the common pitfalls (CR at the end, BOM at the beginning, the fact that multiple options separated by spaces don't get split into separate arguments), the `#!/usr/bin/env` trick, historical trivia (`csh` script detection before `#!`), and some related skills like recognizing error messages from different shells so you can diagnose a failed `#!`

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley the fact that I only recognise half of the things you're talking about proves you right, IMO.

Comment: BoltClock, I agree with you that the title change was not only unnecessary but probably actively harmful; the old title seems like it'd be better for searchers. I have undone the title change and kept the retag. Enforcing conformity in how the *tags* are used needn't (and IMO shouldn't) mean enforcing conformity in how the words are used in prose. @KevinBrown, any thoughts?

Comment: BoltClock, That appears to be the only one I did it for, and I have no idea why I did it. @MarkAmery Thanks for the reverting it.

Comment: Given the prevalence of the term "hashtag" a certain bird-related social media network and the almost sexist term "shebang", don't you think it's time we just destroyed `[shebang]` altogether and replaced with the more-current `[hashbang]`?

Comment: @IanMacDonald For that matter, we could do worse than to accept [Bell Labs terminology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign#Other_names_in_English) and I quite like the idea of an `[octobang]`

Comment: Considering the origin of the word "shebang" is almost certainly either French or Irish Gaelic, any sexist connotations seem rather spurious. (http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shebang)

Answer (score 26):

After [quickly filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hashbang+-javascript+-php+-ajax+-seo+-url+-jquery+-angularjs) out most of the web tags, I could only find three [hashbang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hashbang) questions that should be [shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shebang). These were all tagged [hashbang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hashbang) + [shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell), and I've retagged them as [shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shebang) as there weren't many.

The tag wiki for [hashbang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hashbang) should be updated to point users to [shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shebang) for shell-related questions.

Comment: There should at least be a hint in the hashbang tag about existance of shebang.  Otherwhise within a couple of monthes you'll get to retag again

Comment: There are also 6 double-tagged ones...

Comment: I've just suggested an edit to the [tag:hashbang] wiki and excerpt to point users to [tag:shebang].

Comment: @Deduplicator I've also just fixed the double-tagged ones and reviewed [tag:hashbang] for any others that needed to be retagged.

Answer (score 4):

A quick google search shows that:

- the term `hashbang` is found 178 000 times.  And in 125 000 cases it's together with the term `shell`.
- the term `shebang` is used 890 000 times, but only in 207 000 cases together with `shell`.
- the term `shebang` is used 93 000 times in an `AJAX` context

This shows that while `shebang` is a better alternative for the shellscript related posts, there is a huge common use of `hashbang` for that as well.

I think that you shouldn't hope to be able to rely on a restrictive tag definition (especially a relatively rare tag) against such a huge common use. In addition, these tags are seldom used alone, so that it's easy to guess in which context they are used.

I propose to leave the tags as they are (eventually promoting shebang preference for shellscripts, but not disallowing the alternative usage, as if it doesn't exist).

Comment: We're only dealing with a few hundred questions total, here; maintaining some usage norm wouldn't be hard. If we're not going to disambiguate them, it would seem to make sense to either burninate or merge them, but both of those seem like worse options.

Comment: @MarkAmery I agree.  Merging them would be indeed an excellent idea ! Both refer to the symbols "#!" and only the other tags can permit 100% for sure to identify what it's about.

Comment: Other tags permit identifying what the question is about *if you're looking at an individual question*. Relying on other tags, though, is still a nuisance if you want to follow [tag:shebang] because you're an expert in Unix shebangs (I *think* such a person could plausible exist) or if you want to learn about Unix shebangs by looking at all the questions about them. By accepting a totally ambiguous tag, you're diluting its value in exchange for saving what would be, in this case, a fairly small amount of maintenance. Doesn't seem worth it to me, though YMMV and that's fair enough.

Comment: I understand the problem. But if you're a unix expert, and you don't want to miss a question you might have to follow shebang and hashbang.  Inverstely, if you're an AJAX expert, you might need to follow sheebang as well (as some of the 8 [shebang][ajax] and 6 [hashbang][shebang] suggest)

Comment: @Christophe How did you write a google query to get those stats?

Comment: @Christophe By merging the tags into [tag:hashbang], it makes the tag ambiguous which is [one of the criteria for burnination](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239190/159034). And by classifying it as a context-relative tag (like you're proposing), it makes the problem even worse. As part of the retagging process, we are supposed to _fix the bad tagging_, which in this case doesn't take much work.

Comment: @KevinBrown I don't think it's a good idea to ignore the natural linguisitic ambiguity of the two terms, and create an artificial difference.  If you want to disambiguate, then you should rename the hashbang tag to make the difference really apparent, e.g. `url-hashbang` (and in the description refer to shebang for shell related topics)

Comment: @Christophe Great idea, renaming [tag:hashbang] would solve part of the issue. I've got pending edits for the [tag:hashbang] tag wiki in the queue that will point users to [tag:shebang] for related questions as well.